# How to use VSCode Prettier 3 formatting with stylelint

Tags: visual-studio-code, lint, prettier, stylelint

To be honest I can't understand the documentation or i miss something. It drives me crazy

Steps that i did:

1. Installed VSCode
2. Installed [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) plugin
3. Opened simply project with couple files (html, css)
4. Installed stylelint with `npm install --save-dev stylelint`
5. Installed stylelint-prettier with `npm install --save-dev stylelint-prettier prettier`
6. Created .stylelintrc with content:

```
{
  "plugins": ["stylelint-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": true,
    "comment-empty-line-before": "always",
  }
}
```

And what now? Prettier in VSCode didn't fix anything in css files
Or maybe I do it completely wrong?

I'm working on Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check the answer to this problem on github, where I made a ticket some time ago:

https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/1051

---

#### I now have a better solution for using stylelint in VSCode:

I have a better option to use the stylelint, because the stylelint owner have created the **official VSCode plugin!**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint

The plugin works **almost** out of the box. What you need to do is set up. You can use just settings.json in VSCode. Small example:

```
"stylelint.config": {
    "rules": {
        "at-rule-name-case": "lower",
        "at-rule-name-space-after": "always-single-line",
        "at-rule-semicolon-newline-after": "always",
    }
}
```

#### Do you need a ready-to-use configuration?

No problem - you have to check this

- https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard
- https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-recommended

#### Do you need Formatting option (Shift + Alt + F)?

No problem. You can define keybinding for option `Fix all auto-fixable problems`. For example:

```
{
    "key": "alt+shift+f",
    "command": "stylelint.executeAutofix",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'css'"
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+f",
    "command": "stylelint.executeAutofix",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'scss'"
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+f",
    "command": "stylelint.executeAutofix",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'less'"
}
```

*Remember that not all stylelint options are available for autofixing (but most are)*

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how can I enable it for scss files? It's only working with `.css` and not `.scss` and I couldn't understand the stylelint docs.

Comment: Just found it and edited your answer!